# How to add row to ACF repeater field in Term

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I have a taxonomy with an ACF repeater field. I am trying to add rows in a callback for a custom REST API endpoint and having no luck. The scheme for the field is:

```
 {
                        "key": "field_5faa2bc09fe7b",
                        "label": "team",
                        "name": "team",
                        "type": "repeater",
                        "instructions": "",
                        "required": 0,
                        "conditional_logic": 0,
                        "wrapper": {
                            "width": "",
                            "class": "",
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        "collapsed": "",
                        "min": 0,
                        "max": 10,
                        "layout": "table",
                        "button_label": "",
                        "sub_fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "field_5faa2bce9fe7c",
                                "label": "Role",
                                "name": "role",
                                "type": "post_object",
                                "instructions": "",
                                "required": 0,
                                "conditional_logic": 0,
                                "wrapper": {
                                    "width": "",
                                    "class": "",
                                    "id": ""
                                },
                                "post_type": [
                                    "role"
                                ],
                                "taxonomy": "",
                                "allow_null": 0,
                                "multiple": 0,
                                "return_format": "id",
                                "ui": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "field_5faa2c0b9fe7d",
                                "label": "User",
                                "name": "user",
                                "type": "user",
                                "instructions": "",
                                "required": 0,
                                "conditional_logic": 0,
                                "wrapper": {
                                    "width": "",
                                    "class": "",
                                    "id": ""
                                },
                                "role": "",
                                "allow_null": 0,
                                "multiple": 0,
                                "return_format": "id"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

I use the following to add a row to the field - and having no luck:

```
function wp_api_assign_internal_writer() {
  register_rest_route( 'mynamespace/v1', 'assign_internal_writer/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'assign_internal_writer_callback',
    ));
}


function assign_internal_writer_callback( $request ) {
$parameters = $request->get_params();
$task = $parameters['task'];
$user = $parameters['user'];
$project_set = $parameters['project_set'];
  if($task != '' && $user != '' && $project_set != '' ){

     $row = array(
        'field_5faa2bce9fe7c' => '268',
        'field_5faa2c0b9fe7d' => $user
        );

        add_row('team', $row, $project_set);
        return get_term_meta($project_set);

  }else{
      return 'Please supply the correct request parameters, Task ID and User ID';
  }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Does add row work only for Post and not Term....? I doubt thats it...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your ACF field type i can only suggest to check if it actually expect the real object for the Wp_Post and for the Wp_User. Maybe try to convert your id's into objects and see if it works.

If that's not the issue please be more clear about what you mean with "had no luck". Does that mean you have fatal errors? no warning? no row inserted? ecc...

Comment: Thank you that is helpful. I will take a look.

What I mean is that no row is inserted - the post meta is the same before and after the callback runs